# Getting pythons ElementTree Library to preserve namespaces of parsed files

Tags: python, xml, namespaces, elementtree, preserve

I need to manipulate XML-Files with a python-Script to generate testdata for a legacy application. That means open file, read it do some manipulations and write to file. 
For the target system to be able to treat my testdata namespaces MUST be kept in their original shape. The files I am treating contain lines like xmlns:EHC-1234="URI".

Since the elementTree Library usually replaces each namespace with a new one such as ns0: ns1: etc. I came up with this ugly thing here:

```
            #hack to preserve namespaces
            for elem in ET.iterparse(xmlFile):
                    try:
                            try:
                                    if elem[0][0] == "E":
                                            ET.register_namespace(elem[0], elem[1])
                            except TypeError:
                                    pass
                    except IndexError:
                            pass

            tree = ET.parse(xmlFile)
            #do stuff
            .....
            tree.write(filename, xml_declaration=True, encoding='utf-8', method="xml")
```

This obviously is quick and dirty. (Note that I need to swallow all kinds of errors because there are lots of other tags, not just namespace definitions in the file I'm parsing. I also have to parse my file twice, because the namespaces must be registered before parsing a file in order to be in effect when writing to file again.). I wonder however how one  would do this in a nice way ? Do you have any ideas? I tried to google it, but didn't find an easy solution, so maybe there is a "best practice" somewhere in here :)

Thanks and cheers
Mischa

Comment: Isn't there a predefined set of namespaces? Or are you getting XML documents with previously unknown namespaces all the time?

Comment: I'm getting 8 different types of XML's with different sets of namespaces. In principle I could add them all manually to the namespace_map, but that does not seem like an elegant solution either to me.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a great way to do it, but I basically do the same interparse looking for "start-ns" (start Namespace) events only, then register the Namespace whenever I see one start.

p_infile is a variable containing the name of the file I am about to parse.

"events" needs to be a list, but we only want "start-ns" in it.

```
events = "start-ns", 
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(p_infile, events):
   if event == "start-ns":
       ET.register_namespace(elem[0], elem[1])
       print("registered element " + str(elem))
```

The "if event == start-ns" test is obviously redundant but if I want to do other things with other events like "start" or "end-ns" later, I have the structure there.  So without most terse I can figure would be:

```
events = "start-ns", 
for event, elem in ET.iterparse(p_infile, events):
    ET.register_namespace(elem[0], elem[1])
```

I have only done limited testing on this with XMLs with a single namespace, caveat emptor.